# replace domain name by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

### replace domain name by js or jquery

my old domain is : **www.a.com**

---

new domain is : **www.b.com**

---

how to replace all **a href links** and **canonical** url with new domain
for example

```
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">test</a>
```

replace with

```
<a href="http://www.b.com/a.html">test</a>
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://a.com/a.html">
```

replace with

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://b.com/a.html">
```

Comment: This seems a bit of a hacky solution. Why would you not update the source directly?

Comment: It could be part of a bookmarklet intended to replace website.com with archiveofwebsite.com (practically speaking, replace reddit.com with removeddit.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`URL api`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to find and replace `hostname`

```js
const anchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a')
anchorTags.forEach( anchor => {
  const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
  const parsed = new URL(href)
  if (parsed.hostname === 'www.a.com') {
    parsed.hostname = 'www.b.com'
    anchor.setAttribute('href', parsed)
  }
})
console.log([...anchorTags.values()])
```

```html
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">Link 3</a>
<a href="http://www.c.com/a.html">This link should not be touched</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to do this and not sure where your `<link>` elements are located
But to change the href of the `a` elements you can use this

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('a')
a.forEach((elem) => {
  const href = elem.getAttribute('href');
  if ( href.includes('www.a.com') ) {
   elem.setAttribute('href', href.replace('www.a.com','www.b.com'))
  }
})
console.log(a)
```

```html
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">test</a>
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">test2</a>
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">test3</a>
<a href="http://www.c.com/a.html">dont change me</a>
```

Comment: well it's the same. Just select them in document.qureySelectorAll. Where are they located ?

Comment: @CodeManiac touche`